# Backbone JS: Issue related to click event and POST request

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am new to Backbone and just finished a simple `get` request.
 Trying to implement a simple POST request.

Use case:
When user clicks on `Transfer` button input field values will be sent to a REST API as a JSON object.

`<div id="transfer">
    <input type="text" placeholder="From Address" id="fromAddress" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="To Address" id="toAddress" />
    <input type="text" placeholder="Amount" id="dollars" />
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Transfer"/>
</div>`

**Issue 1**
First problem is that what will go into the `Backbone View`.
**My Backbone View:**

```
var TransferView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        "click #button": "sendMoney"
    },
    sendMoney: function() {
        alert();
        console.log($("#fromAddress").val());
            //this.model.transferMoney($("#fromAddress").val(), 
                $("#toAddress").val(), $("#dollars").val());
    }
});

var transferView = new TransferView();
transferView.render();
```

When I click on button nothing happens. What is the issue here?

**Issue 2**
Backbone Model looks like this.

```
var Money = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/sendMoney',
    defaults: {
        fromAddress: "",
        toAddress: "",
        amount: ""
    },
    transferMoney: function(request, response) {
        //get field values?
        this.save();
    }
});

var transferMoney = new Money();
```

Flow didn't reach the model yet, but I am not sure how would I fetch `fromAddress, toAddress and amount` values from `req`?
 How would I pass the request parameters in JSON format to REST service?

> **Note:** Can not use `form` here. It is more like a ajax request.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to have enough detail in order to see what exactly is going on.  Can you post it as a jsFiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issues with your view are :

- you're missing a `template`
- you have a syntax error in `$("#toAddress").val(), $("#dollars").val());`

Since the view doesn't have a template, nothing gets displayed and therefore there is no "#button" to attach events to. Also, don't forget you'll typicallly need to provide a `Money` model instance to the view, so that you can then set attributes on it.

To pass value from the form, just use the `val()` method.

And to send data to the API, you just need to `save`: Backbone does the rest.

Basically, what you probably want to have is something like

```
var TransferView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        "click #button": "sendMoney"
    },
    sendMoney: function() {
        this.model.save({
            fromAddress: $("#fromAddress").val(),
            toAddress: $("#toAddress").val(),
            amount: $("#dollars").val(),
        });
    }
});
```

And to instanciate the view:

```
var money = new Money();
var transferView = new TransferView({ model: money });
```

It would probably be a good investment of your time to read a few Backbone tutorials, such as http://coenraets.org/blog/2011/12/backbone-js-wine-cellar-tutorial-part-1-getting-started/

To delegate saving to a model method, do something like:

```
var Money = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url: 'http://localhost:3000/sendMoney',
    defaults: {
        fromAddress: "",
        toAddress: "",
        amount: ""
    },
    transferMoney: function(attributes) {
        this.save(attributes);
    }
});

var TransferView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        "click #button": "sendMoney"
    },
    sendMoney: function() {
        this.model.transferMoney({
            fromAddress: $("#fromAddress").val(),
            toAddress: $("#toAddress").val(),
            amount: $("#dollars").val(),
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply @David. One more thing I don't want to call model's save from View. I want to delegate `save()` to model itself. How would I send view's input values to model's `transferMoney()`